# change object asynchronously inside a loop and then return the modified object

Tags: loops, promise, bluebird

The problem is that the "then" fires before the "getUsernameById" has done it's job in the loop.

```
var dummyObject = {
    choices: [
        {
            votes: [
                "1234",
                "2143",
                "4321"
            ]
        }
    ]
};

Promise.each(dummyObject.choices, function(choice, i) {
    dummyObject.choices[i].test = "test"; // this gets changed before 'then'
    Promise.each(choice.votes, function(vote, j) {
        getUsernameById(vote).then(function(username) {
            dummyObject.choices[i].votes[j] = username; // this gets changed after 'then'
        });
    });
}).then(function() {
    res.json(dummyObject);
});
```

Can this even be done ?

Comment: If you're using some promises library which provides `Promise.each`, please tag your question with its name. BTW, are you sure you are not missing a `return` here or there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you. Pretty much what's going on is `getUsernameById` is returning a promise, evidenced by the fact that we're calling `then` on it, and `then` itself returns a promise. So what we're doing is for each vote associated with each choice, we're putting a promise into our `promises` array. Each of these promises is resolved after the username has been obtained and the correct vote and choice has been modified.

Then you can use `all` on the promises array, which return a promise that is resolved after all of the promises in the `promises` array have been resolved. Your last `then` will only fire after all of this has happened, and by this time, your dummyObject should be updated properly.

```
var dummyObject = {
    choices: [
        {
            votes: [
                "1234",
                "2143",
                "4321"
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var promises = [];

dummyObject.choices.forEach(function (choice, i) {
  choice.votes.forEach(function (vote, j) {
    var userPromise = getUsernameById(vote).then(function (username) {
      dummyObject.choices[i].votes[j] = username;
    });

    promises.push(userPromise);        
  });
});

return Promises.all(promises).then(function () {
  res.json(dummyObject);
});
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any quesstions.